# Integrate javascript widget in jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook

I am looking for a way to display this [javascript widget](https://codepen.io/diallobakary4/pen/MZzKZz?editors=0010) inside Jupiter lab or notebook. The widget uses [nglview](https://github.com/arose/nglview). 
I tried simply running the javascript code in Jupyter but I am getting this error.

```
Javascript error adding output!
ReferenceError: NGL is not defined
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

Now nglview is a python module. I tried first converting the javascript code to pythin using [js2py](https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py). But I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, you can utilize Deno as the kernel for your Jupyter environment. Deno provides a secure runtime for JavaScript and TypeScript, which might help resolve the issue you're facing with nglview.

You can install Deno and set it up as the kernel for your Jupyter environment following the instructions provided in the Deno documentation. Once Deno is set up, you can then run your JavaScript code within the Deno environment, which should hopefully resolve the "NGL is not defined" error you're encountering.
Here you can find more abot it:
https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/tools/jupyter